# When starting a new app do you support only the latest iOS or at least one before it?

Tags: ios, ios6

I hope this question will not be closed for being subjective but i think it would be interesting to know for new developers.  This question is relevant for every iOS release. 
I am working an iPhone application for a while now and it's ready to be submitted to the app store.  With 60% iOS adaptation rate should i just set my app to the iOS 6.0 and up or still keep at 5?  What is the usual practice for new apps?  I might want to use UICollectionview in this app at later time but it might be harder to require higher os within a short period of time.  It is an iPhone only app so i am not hitting the iPad 1 market.  If you are developing iPad app would you stick with 5 because of the iPad 1?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I still develop for iOS 5.  iOS 5's improvements were such a leap from previous versions that I started building for it on an app that was released shortly after the iOS5 release.  I haven't seen anything major in the jump to iOS 6, at least nothing that I consider worth losing/aggravating my iPad 1 users and throwing out all of the iOS 5 market share.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  It's true that in iOS 6 there only few features that you would use unless you building something more specific geared toward iOS 6 users like passbook app.